# Which library on windows is used to encrypt and decrypt messages while using TLS/SSL?

Tags: ssl

I wish to write a small IM client. If you can also provide links to some literature/sample code that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing native code, you're probably going to want to look at [SSPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380535%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and specifially [SChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374782%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> The Schannel security package provides access to four security protocols:

- Transport Layer Security (TLS 1.2)
- Transport Layer Security (TLS 1.1)
- Transport Layer Security (TLS 1.0)
- Secure Sockets Layer (SSL 3.0)
- Secure Sockets Layer (SSL 2.0)

Let's ignore for the moment that they can't count :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language / platform (.NET, Win32 API etc.) there are several options available.

SChannel has been mentioned above. Then you can use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/). Also depending on your platform you can use our [SSLBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-ssl.php).